# jQuery FullCalendar invoking populate data method failing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, razor, fullcalendar

I am currently working on a little website in ASP.NET MVC3 (Razor) where I need a page that displays a calendar with some appointments in it.

I have chosen FullCalendar and have run into some trouble. I got the calendar displaying fine by injecting it into a `<div>`.

But as soon as I try to add the "events" property so that my populate data method is invoked the calendar is not even being show and naturally I never reach the method in the controller. Even if I try to add a header section where I manipulate the title and navigation arrows it wont render.

I have included all the necessary scripts in my masterpage here is the source view of the index view were you can see all the scripts included.

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. I should be able to render the HTML just fine and invoke the method so I get some appointments in my calendar.

Also why can I not do a simple operation like modifying the header and positioning the title where I want. My syntax must be broken?

```
   <title>Index</title>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/Venatores.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Datamodel:

```
 public class EventModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
}
```

Controller named CalendarController:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }



    public JsonResult PopulateData(double start, double end)
    {

      //  var startDateTime = FromUnixTimestamp(start);
       // var endDateTime = FromUnixTimestamp(end);

        EventModel appointment = new EventModel();
        appointment.StartDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        appointment.EndDateTime = appointment.StartDateTime.AddHours(2.0);
        appointment.IsAllDay = false;
        appointment.Title = "Riffel";
        appointment.ID = 1;

        List<EventModel> appointments = new List<EventModel>();
        appointments.Add(appointment);

        var clientList = new List<object>();

        foreach (EventModel e in appointments)
        {
            clientList.Add(
                new
                    {
                        id = e.ID,
                        title = e.Title,
                        //description = e.Description,
                        start = ToUnixTimespan(e.StartDateTime),
                        end = ToUnixTimespan(e.EndDateTime),
                        allDay = e.IsAllDay,
                        url = "www.google.com"
                });
        }
        return Json(clientList.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    private static DateTime FromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
    {
        var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
    }

    private long ToUnixTimespan(DateTime date)
    {
        TimeSpan tspan = date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));

        return (long)Math.Truncate(tspan.TotalSeconds);
    }
```

My Index view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //events: "/Calendar/PopulateData"
        });
    });

</script>

<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work in ASP - but, the FullCalendar API seems to require the "url" setting if you want to use a server-side JSON callback.  The "events" setting is for client-side array or function population.  Other than that - on the surface - most of the rest of it looks to make sense.